# React + Node + Firebase, how to deploy build folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I actually had a react app which was running after a build in my node backend folder and run perfectly.

Is it possible to do the same with firebase ?
I manage to run my build folder like this in my firebase.json :

```
   "public": "build",

"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

But this not contain my node app.
My node app is build approximately like this :

```
-myapp
   -/build
   -/route
      -mail.js
   -app.js
```

and app.js contain :

```
app.use('/send', mail);
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
```

})

My node app is here to send email via nodemailer.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got 2 options

1. Deploy backend to a server (you can do that for free with Heroku/Netifly etc...), and use `fetch` at the front end to that endpoint to run the script, because at the same firebase domain both React app and node server are not live together
2. if you need backend just for sending emails, you might consider use https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs-com because they allow sending emails directly from front-end (also with a free limited usage..)

Comment: Thank you so much, I’l look into that :)